# Class Cast Exception with java.util.function.DoublePredicate

Tags: java, java-stream, predicate

I am writing an application for fun involving getting the average from an array, and using DoubleStream and DoublePredicate to filter, then count above and below a calculated average. Here's the code below. Why is my inner class incompatible with DoublePredicate?

**error**
The average salary of the employee is: 23914.0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: EmployeeRecord$GreaterThanSalary incompatible with java.util.function.DoublePredicate
at EmployeeRecordDriver.calculateGreaterThanLessThanSalary(EmployeeRecordDriver.java:24)
at EmployeeRecordDriver.main(EmployeeRecordDriver.java:13)

Thanks

**EmployeeRecordDriver.java**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.function.DoublePredicate;
import java.util.stream.DoubleStream;   


public class EmployeeRecordDriver {
    
    private static double salary[] = {23500.0, 25080.0, 28760.0, 22340.0, 19890.0};
    private static EmployeeRecord record;
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("The average salary of the employee is: " + findAverage(salary));
        System.out.println("The number of employees having a salary greater than the average is: " + calculateGreaterThanLessThanSalary(salary) ); // line 13
//      System.out.println("The number of employees having a salary less than the average is: " + calculateLessThanLessThanSalary(salary) );
    }
    
    public static double findAverage(double[] salary) {
        record = new EmployeeRecord(0.0, salary);
        return record.averageSalary;
    }
        
    public static int calculateGreaterThanLessThanSalary(double salary[]) {
        int info[] = new int[2];
        info[0] = (int)Arrays.asList(salary).stream().flatMapToDouble(element -> DoubleStream.of(element)).filter((DoublePredicate) record.gts).count(); // line 24
        return info[0];
    }
}
```

**EmployeeRecord.java**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.stream.DoubleStream;

public class EmployeeRecord{
    
    double averageSalary = 0.0;
    double[] salary = new double[5];
    GreaterThanSalary<Double> gts = new GreaterThanSalary<>();
    
    public EmployeeRecord(double averageSalary, double[] salary) {
        super();
        this.averageSalary = this.calculateAverage(salary);
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public double calculateAverage(double salary[]) {
        double sum = Arrays.asList(salary).stream().flatMapToDouble(num -> DoubleStream.of(num)).sum();
        return sum/salary.length;
    }
    
    public class GreaterThanSalary<DoublePredicate> implements Predicate<Double>{
        @Override
        public boolean test(Double d) {
            return d > averageSalary;   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `DoubleSalary` in `GreaterThanSalary<DoublePredicate>` is a generic type *name*. It's not actually java.util.function.DoublePredicate. And it's not actually doing anything as far as I can see. Did you mean to write `implements DoublePredicate`?

Comment: Instead of `double sum = Arrays.asList(salary).stream().flatMapToDouble(num -> DoubleStream.of(num)).sum(); return sum/salary.length;`, you can simply use `return Arrays.stream(salary).average();`. The same applies to the stream you use for counting the matches, except that you added an entirely obsolete array, i.e. `int info[] = new int[2];`. Further, don’t use this C syntax having `[]` following the variable name or at least, be consistent, don’t switch between these styles.

Comment: This one worked. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

`EmployeeRecord.gts` implements `Predicate<Double>`, and you're trying to cast it to `DoublePredicate`. These are similar but not identical interfaces (`DoublePredicate` uses the primitive `double` type while `Predicate<Double>` uses boxing).

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `Predicate<Double>` and other unnecessary generics. Your solution (`flatMapToDouble` produces `DoubleStream`) requires `DoublePredicate` in the `filter` method. And `DoublePredicate` differs from `Predicate<Double>`. They are not related even though they look almost the same.

EmployeeRecord.java:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.function.DoublePredicate;
import java.util.stream.DoubleStream;

public class EmployeeRecord{
    
    double averageSalary = 0.0;
    double[] salary = new double[5];
    DoublePredicate gts = new GreaterThanSalary();
    
    public EmployeeRecord(double averageSalary, double[] salary) {
        super();
        this.averageSalary = this.calculateAverage(salary);
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public double calculateAverage(double salary[]) {
        double sum = Arrays.asList(salary).stream().flatMapToDouble(num -> DoubleStream.of(num)).sum();
        return sum/salary.length;
    }
    
    public class GreaterThanSalary implements DoublePredicate{
        @Override
        public boolean test(double d) {
            return d > averageSalary;   
        }
    }
}
```

EmployeeRecordDriver.java:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.function.DoublePredicate;
import java.util.stream.DoubleStream;   


public class EmployeeRecordDriver {
    
    private static double salary[] = {23500.0, 25080.0, 28760.0, 22340.0, 19890.0};
    private static EmployeeRecord record;
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("The average salary of the employee is: " + findAverage(salary));
        System.out.println("The number of employees having a salary greater than the average is: " + calculateGreaterThanLessThanSalary(salary) ); // line 13
//      System.out.println("The number of employees having a salary less than the average is: " + calculateLessThanLessThanSalary(salary) );
    }
    
    public static double findAverage(double[] salary) {
        record = new EmployeeRecord(0.0, salary);
        return record.averageSalary;
    }
        
    public static int calculateGreaterThanLessThanSalary(double salary[]) {
        int info[] = new int[2];
        info[0] = (int)Arrays.asList(salary).stream().flatMapToDouble(element -> DoubleStream.of(element)).filter(record.gts).count(); // line 24
        return info[0];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input. I turns out I did need DoublePredicate. I found it by finding another class ending with "Predicate" suffix in [allclasses-noframe](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/allclasses-noframe.html)
What concept in Java enables us to refer to an object that implements an interface by the type of interface as in     DoublePredicate gts = new GreaterThanSalary(); ?

**EmployeeRecordDriver.java**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.function.DoublePredicate;
import java.util.stream.DoubleStream;   


public class EmployeeRecordDriver {
    
    private static double salary[] = {23500.0, 25080.0, 28760.0, 22340.0, 19890.0};
    private static EmployeeRecord record;
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("The average salary of the employee is: " + findAverage(salary));
        System.out.println("The number of employees having a salary greater than the average is: " + calculateGreaterThanSalary(salary) );
        System.out.println("The number of employees having a salary less than the average is: " + calculateLessThanSalary(salary) );
    }
    
    public static double findAverage(double[] salary) {
        record = new EmployeeRecord(0.0, salary);
        return record.averageSalary;
    }
        
    public static int calculateGreaterThanSalary(double salary[]) {
        int count = (int)Arrays.stream(salary).filter((DoublePredicate) record.gts).count(); // line 24
        return count;
    }
    
    public static int calculateLessThanSalary(double salary[]) {
        int count = (int)Arrays.stream(salary).filter((DoublePredicate) record.lts).count(); // line 24
        return count;
    }
}
```

**EmployeeRecord.java**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.function.DoublePredicate;

public class EmployeeRecord{
    
    double averageSalary = 0.0;
    double[] salary = new double[5];
    DoublePredicate gts = new GreaterThanSalary();
    DoublePredicate lts = new LessThanSalary();
    
    public EmployeeRecord(double averageSalary, double[] salary) {
        this.averageSalary = this.calculateAverage(salary);
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public double calculateAverage(double salary[]) {
        return Arrays.stream(salary).average().getAsDouble();
    }
    
    public class GreaterThanSalary implements DoublePredicate{
        @Override
        public boolean test(double d) {
            return d > averageSalary;   
        }
    }
    
    public class LessThanSalary implements DoublePredicate{
        @Override
        public boolean test(double d) {
            return d < averageSalary;   
        }
    }
}
```